# What is a "blazor circuit"?

Tags: blazor-server-side

There are plenty of mentions to "Blazor circuit" term on the documentation, however I cannot find a definition of the term. I guess it is something like some kind of state associated to the user session.

Please, could you provide a more precise definition of what a Blazor circuit really is?

Answer (score 2):

From MS [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) :

> Blazor Server is a stateful framework. While users interact with an app, they maintain a connection to the server known as a circuit. The circuit holds active component instances, plus many other aspects of state, such as:
>
> - The most recent rendered output of components.
> - The current set of event-handling delegates that could be triggered by client-side events.