# Blazor - Stripe payment integration

Tags: blazor

In my Blazor app I am using Stripe Checkout and I can process payments successfully.
My issue is that on a successful payment the return Success - URL page supplied to Stripe is seems go into another instance of my app.  After a successful payment  all pages I navigate now  shows the default values as though I restarted the program.
How do the I ensure the success URL page  passed to Stripe is the actual URL of my current instance?

Comment: You provide insufficient details... What kind of hosting model do you use? How are you calling the Stripe API?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Server hosted Blazor has a "session" concept known as "Blazor circuit". When you navigate away from a Blazor page to some other site, the circuit is broken and all session data is disposed of. When you navigate back, even with the same URL, a new circuit will be created. You must ensure that you save and load data as required based on URL token or some other mechanism.

In a traditional server-rendered app, opening the same app in multiple browser screens (tabs or iframes) typically doesn't translate into additional resource demands on the server. In a Blazor Server app, each browser screen requires a separate circuit and separate instances of server-managed component state. Blazor considers closing a browser tab or navigating to an external URL a graceful termination. In the event of a graceful termination, the circuit and associated resources are immediately released. A client may also disconnect non-gracefully, for instance due to a network interruption. Blazor Server stores disconnected circuits for a configurable interval to allow the client to reconnect.

See also:

[Blazor hosting models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models)

[Blazor state management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management)

Comment: While not a complete answer, this helps. I tried to track down a reference for _Blazor Circuit_ which would help this anwer, so so far only found this unanswered question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61982339/1690217

Comment: Updated this answer and answered the question about Blazor state management.